# Magento displaying style as text on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, magento, mobile

When trying to look at the products in the store on a mobile device, it will show the style of the products as text instead of applying it. 
This will only display as text on mobile devices and does work the way it is supposed to on regular browsers (computer).

On mobile devices it will be displayed like this:

```
<b>Intel Quad Core - I7 - 6700HQ</b> 
(2.6GHz - 3.5Ghz)) 6MB cache­ (SKYLAKE) <b>
<font color=“#4CC417”>45 Watt</b></font> Intel® HD 530
```

After trying to disable JavaScript execution in the computer browser, it will only display the text as style as well.

Here is an example of the computer browser:
[image: Working PC version]
Below is an example of the device version of the same product:
[image: Device version where style is displayed as text]

After disabling JavaScript on the computer, the PC version will also look like the mobile version. So my best guess here is that it has to do with a JavaScript problem.

We've been on this problem for several days now and can't find a working solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: added part of code where we expect to find the problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
 var Brchecked="1";
 function Bmouseo(tyu){if(Brchecked!=tyu)     {
document.getElementById("hover-"+tyu).style.backgroundColor="#155565";}}
 function Bmouseo2(tyu){if(Brchecked!=tyu)    {     document.getElementById("hover-"+tyu).style.backgroundColor="transparent";     document.getElementById("hover-"+tyu).style.color="#ffffff";}}
</script>
```

[image: Possible problem]
Edit: after this code has been executed, the problem is resolved and the text is displayed the way it is supposed to be.

```
changeSelection: function(selection){       
    parts = selection.id.split('-');
    if (this.config['options'][parts[2]].isMulti) {
        selected = new Array();
        if (selection.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.options.length; i++) {
                if (selection.options[i].selected && selection.options[i].value != '') {                        
                    selected.push(selection.options[i].value);
                    //this.showName(parts[2], selection.options[i]);

                }
            }
        } else if (selection.tagName == 'INPUT') {
            selector = parts[0]+'-'+parts[1]+'-'+parts[2];
            selections = $$('.'+selector);
            for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
                if (selections[i].checked && selections[i].value != '') {                       
                    selected.push(selections[i].value);
                    alert(selections[i].value);
                    //this.showName(parts[2], selections[i]);

                }
            }               
        }
        this.config.selected[parts[2]] = selected;
    } else {
        if (selection.value != '') {
            this.config.selected[parts[2]] = new Array(selection.value);

        } else {
            this.config.selected[parts[2]] = new Array();
        }
        this.populateQty(parts[2], selection.value);
        //this.showName(parts[2], selection);           
    }
    this.changeTitlePriceLabel(parts[2], selection.value);
    this.changeTagActive(parts[2], selection.value);
    //alert(selection.value);
    this.showName();
    this.reloadPrice();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in your header section of the page the following is present and in this specific order

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Create a table with the results and add a Hover effect in CSS for table

```
tr:hover td {
color: #000;
background: #FFF8DC;
}
```

Comment: We've checked this and all above are present and in that order, is there any other option we can try?

Comment: why use javascript to get the results, use css instead

Comment: The style needs to be added dynamically, I expect that to be the reason there has been chosen to use JavaScript in the past.

Comment: see the hover effect with css that I added above, It has the same result

Comment: This however only will turn all the text black, am I right? Also the parts that we needed colored

Comment: view this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pc92pvk/) I made, it should help you out